# how to avoid window view to come over Keyboard?

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I have window view in bottom and when i click on any edittext, keyboard opens but below windows view (Windowview comes over keyboard).
Tried using adjustPan, adjustResize.
Tried using show hide the view as per keyboard visibility but it give Security Exception.

```
 mTabParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

        mTabParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        mTabParams.height = TAB_BAR_HEIGHT;
        mTabParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        mWindowmanager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mWindowmanager.addView(mTabbarLayout, mTabParams);
```

Comment: `int TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY Window type: system overlay windows, which need to be displayed on top of everything else.` So try removing that flag and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me :

```
params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams( 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SPLIT_TOUCH | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM, 
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

This put the added view behind the keyboard.

Comment: Specifically I found that FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM were the flags needed, the others are optional depending on your specific needs